# Displaying pyqtgraph and pyqt widgets on web

Tags: python, django, pyqt, saas, pyqtgraph

Is there a way to take existing python pyqtgraph and pyqt application and have it display on a web page to implement software as a service? I suspect that there has to be a supporting web framework like Django in between, but I am not sure how this is done.

Any hints links examples welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have sort of put together by pulling several threads online:

1. Ruby On Rails seems to be more popular than python at this moment.
2. If you go python, Flask and Django are good templates.
3. bokeh seems to be a good way of plotting to a browser.
4. AFAIK, there is no way to take an existing PyQt or pyqtgraph application and have it run on the web.
5. I am not sure how Twisted (Tornado, Node.js and Friends) fits in to the web SaaS, but I see it referred to occasionally since it is asynchronous event-driven.
6. People often suggest using Rest, but that seems slow to me. Not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

If all you need are static plots, then it should be straightforward to draw and export to an SVG file, then display the SVG in a webpage (or export to image, as svg rendering is not reliable in all browsers). If you need interactivity, then you're going to need a different solution and probably pyqtgraph is not the tool for this job. VisPy does have some early browser support but this has only been demonstrated with ipython notebook.

Comment: Thanks. It needs to be realtime.